# Any way to automatically generate ExecuteSqlCommand or SqlQuery calls based on a given TSQL stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I have many stored procedures that I need to call with `System.Data.Entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` or `System.Data.Entity.Database.SqlQuery`

My stored procedures require many parameters including output parameters. Hand coding the parameter creation might take time and it might be erroneous.

Is there any way to automatically generate `ExecuteSqlCommand` or `SqlQuery` calls based on a given T-SQL stored procedure?

I am aware that I can use an `.edmx` model, but as far as I know, `.edmx` models use function imports. I like to do a direct `ExecuteSqlCommand` or `SqlQuery` call.

Comment: The answer is "No" there is no automatic option. I had to hand code it.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete solution per se, but here are some SQL queries that will return the necessary stored procedure parameter and result information. You can use these with a [T4 Template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) (or similar) to generate your data access code.

Stored procedure parameters:

```
select
    schema_name(sp.schema_id) as schema_name,
    sp.name as procedure_name,
    p.name as parameter_name,
    typ.name as type_name,
    p.max_length,
    p.precision,
    p.scale,
    p.is_output
from sys.procedures sp
left join sys.parameters p on p.object_id = sp.object_id
left join sys.types typ on typ.user_type_id = p.user_type_id
order by schema_name, sp.name, p.parameter_id
```

Stored procedure results:

```
if serverproperty('islocaldb') is not null -- identifies sql server 2012+, which is the first version that supports dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object
or serverproperty('edition') = 'SQL Azure' -- azure sql also supports dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object
    select
        schema_name(sp.schema_id) as schema_name,
        sp.name as procedure_name,
        rs.name as column_name,
        typ.name as type_name,
        rs.max_length,
        rs.precision,
        rs.scale
    from sys.procedures sp
    cross apply sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object(sp.object_id, 0) rs
    join sys.types typ on typ.system_type_id = rs.system_type_id
    order by schema_name, sp.name, rs.column_ordinal
else
    select
        null as schema_name,
        null as procedure_name,
        null as column_name,
        null as type_name,
        null as max_length,
        null as precision,
        null as scale
```